# Including user details in my database alongside HTML

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When a user signs up on my site, I save the details of an email to send to them (such as their email address, name and the contents of the email) into my database. A script (that runs every few seconds) then sends emails out based on the details stored in the database, before deleting the row so emails aren't processed multiple times.

The problem I am having lies in incorporating the user's details into the email body.

Below is a snippet of the HTML code I can put into my database **with no problems**:

```
<span style="font-size:1.5em; font-family:Arial">Welcome!</span><br>
<span style="font-size:1.2em">Hi! Lets get your new account set up!</span>
```

However, I want to be more user-friendly and instead of saying 'Welcome!', I want to be able to say 'Welcome, username!'. So, I tried this:

```
<span style="font-size:1.5em; font-family:Arial">Welcome, ' . $username . '!</span><br>
<span style="font-size:1.2em">Hi! Lets get your new account set up!</span>
```

I am using the htmlspecialchars() PHP function, but the above code simply will not be inserted into the database. The above code is in a variable $message, which I then use the htmlspecialchars() function on before attempting to insert into the database.

I have tried to change all the ' to " in the ' . $username . ' part. This **will be inserted into the database without a problem**; however in the email the user receives, instead of seeing something like this:

Welcome Yorkie595!
  Hi! Let's get your new account set up!

...the user receives an email that looks like this:

Welcome " . $username . "!
  Hi! Let's get your new account set up!

In case you need it, here is the SQL query to insert the new row into the database:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mailtosend`
(`id`,`from_email`,`from_name`,`to_email`,`to_name`,`message`,`subject`,`message_nohtml`)
VALUES (NULL, 'emailtosendfrom@mail.com', 'Mail Name', '$email', '$fullname',
'$message', 'Activate your account', 'Activate your account')");
```

So, my question: **how can I incorporate PHP variables such as $username into $message?**

Comment: Can you show more of the PHP code that writes out the span tags?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The HTML code snippet is in a variable, so $message = '<span style="..'; then I do $message = htmlspecialchars($message); so I can actually insert the HTML into the database.

Comment: you shouldn't be storing html in the db. what happens if you decide to change the message? Now you have to hack up who knows how many records. You've got the username somewhere. Use PHP what it was designed for: Keep **ONE** copy of the html in a script somewhere, and fill in the username dynamically as needed.

Comment: Changing the message would be impossible with my setup, which will send the email and delete the record from the database within 5 seconds of it being added. If I was to fill in the username dynamically, however, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough info to investigate why the $message var is not interpolating for you.

Something like this works for me:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli>connect_error;
}

$username = 'freddy';
$message = <<<EOT

<span style="font-size:1.5em; font-family:Arial">Welcome, $username!</span><br>
<span style="font-size:1.2em">Hi! Lets get your new account set up!</span>

EOT;
$message = htmlspecialchars($message);

$sql = <<<EOT

INSERT INTO `mailtosend`
    (`id`,`from_email`,`from_name`,`to_email`,`to_name`,`message`,`subject`,`message_nohtml`)
    VALUES (NULL, 'emailtosendfrom@mail.com', 'Mail Name', ?, ?,
    ?, 'Activate your account', 'Activate your account')

EOT;

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))) {
     echo 'Prepare failed: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ' . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param('sss', $email, $fullname, $message)) {
    echo 'Binding parameters failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo 'Execute failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->close();

?>
```

(Plus added benefit of anti-sql-injection measures.)

UPDATE: I added the MySQLi connection to complete the picture. The MySQLi connection is necessary with the above code.

The `bind_param` function automatically, and optimally escapes prepared statement input strings. `bind_param` secure and replaced the ?'s in the SQL statement with the variables you provide. Here's an answer about "real_escape" vs prepared statements. `mysql_query` is going the way of the dodo, so in my opinion better to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I stripped out the EOT for the SQL query and the stmt and replaced it with mysql_query("") and it all works fine. I had to do a little research on what EOT was but now I know for future reference. With the stmt included, PHP was throwing the errors 'Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli' and 'Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object', both of which occurred on the first line where '$stmt' is present. An explanation of these errors would be helpful if you can ;) also, how does your script help prevent SQL injection? Is mysql_real_escape_string not enough?